# How set Response body in javax.ws.rs.core.Response

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

There is a REST API endpoint which needs to be implemented is used to get some information and send backend request to an another server and response which is coming from backend server has to set the to final response. My problem is **how to set response body in javax.ws.rs.core.Response?**

```
@Path("analytics")
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public Response getDeviceStats(@QueryParam("deviceType") String deviceType,
                               @QueryParam("deviceIdentifier") String deviceIdentifier,
                               @QueryParam("username") String user, @QueryParam("from") long from,
                               @QueryParam("to") long to) {

    // Trust own CA and all self-signed certs
    SSLContext sslcontext = null;
    try {
        sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
                .loadTrustMaterial(new File(getClientTrustStoretFilePath()), "password## Heading ##".toCharArray(),
                        new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                .build();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        log.error(e);
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        log.error(e);
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        log.error(e);
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        log.error(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
            sslcontext,
            new String[] { "TLSv1" },
            null,
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
            .build();
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
        httpget.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=");
        httpget.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        String message = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        log.error(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(e);
    } 

}
```

Here **message** is the one I need to set. But I tried several methods. Didn't work any of them.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

One of the following solutions should do the trick:

```
return Response.ok(entity).build();
```

```
return Response.ok().entity(entity).build();
```

For more details, have a look at [`Response`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) and [`Response.ResponseBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html) classes documentation.

**Tip**: In the [`Response.ResponseBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html) API you might find some useful methods that allow you to add information related to [cache](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html#cacheControl-javax.ws.rs.core.CacheControl-), [cookies](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html#cookie-javax.ws.rs.core.NewCookie...-) and [headers](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html#header-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) to the HTTP response.

Comment: Yes. `return Response.ok(message).build()` works for me. Also `return Response.ok().entity(message).build()`  didn't works . Anyway thanks and acceped answer

Comment: Response.ok(message).build() will return a 200, can we do some thing same to BAD_REQUESTs as well. I mean to add a custom message.

Comment: @prime `return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(entity).build();`